# Foreach in array for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So, I am using codeigniter and I am trying to use the calendar class and pass "events" to my calendar. This is done by an array and an identifier like so:

```
$calendar_info = array(
  'month' => '12',
  'year' => '2013',
  'data' => array(
    3  => 'Spaghetti<br/>Meatballs<br/>Salad<br/>Canned Fruit',
    4  => 'Ham<br/>Mashed Potatoes<br/>Corn<br/>Salad</br>'
   )
);
```

Now I can't hard code the menu items into the application, I am getting them from a database. My problem lies in putting the foreach into the array, I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH, expecting ')'
```

That error is only a portion so not to reveal my web address. Below is what I am trying to do right now and getting the error above.

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('menus');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $session_data['id']);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $calendar_info = array(
        'month' => '12',
        'year' => '2013',
        'data' => array(
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $row->menu_day => $row->menu_entree.'<br/>'.$row->menu_sideone.'<br/>'.$row->menusidetwo.'<br/>'.$row->menudessert
            }
        ),
    );
```

**UPDATE**

This is exactly what I have/am trying to do below:

I have a database table that holds my menu items for each day of the month.

the columns are:

```
menu_day
menu_month
menu_entree
menu_sideone
menu_sidetwo
menu_dessert
```

the array needs to look like this:

```
array(
  menu_day => 'menu_entree<br/>menu_sideone<br/>menu_sidetwo<br/>menu_dessert
)
```

Or for example:

```
array(
  3 => 'Spaghetti<br/>Meatballs<br/>Salad<br/>Canned Fruit'
)
```

Comment: You can't use `foreach` inside array definition. What exactly you are trying to do? How should the array data look like?

Comment: I updated my question to better explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot loop inside an `array()` declaration as you are trying to do. Instead, the right course of action would be to build your array with the loop as you've done, then *assign* it into `$calendar_info['data']`.

Don't think of the PHP code as thing to build dynamically. It's the array data structure you are generating, not the code which defines it.

```
// First build the array with your loop...
// An empty array to hold the result...
$data = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
  // Add array keys to the array while looping...
  $data[$row->menu_day] = $row->menu_entree.'<br/>'.$row->menu_sideone.'<br/>'.$row->menusidetwo.'<br/>'.$row->menudessert;
}

$calendar_info = array(
    'month' => '12',
    'year' => '2013',
    // Then assign it into the appropriate place...
    'data' => $data
);
```

You don't need to build the variable `$data` just to throw away later. You could alternatively first define `$calendar_info` with an empty array in `$calendar_info['data']` then add keys in the `foreach` loop as `$calendar_info['data'][$row->menu_day]`.

Comment: I'm getting an error stating `unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW` I'm guessing it's because of the `=>` in the for each, do we just need to do the following instead?: `"=>".`

Comment: whoops sorry, that should be `=`, not `=>`

Comment: Oh okay. I was not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot put a `foreach` inside an array the way your question has it laid out. You need to set the values ahead of time with a `foreach` loop and then place that array into `$calendar_info` that way:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('menus');
$this->db->where('user_id', $session_data['id']);

$query = $this->db->get();

$data_array = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
  $data_array[$row->menu_day] = $row->menu_entree . '<br/>' . $row->menu_sideone . '<br/>' . $row->menusidetwo . '<br/>' . $row->menudessert;
}

$calendar_info = array(
    'month' => '12',
    'year' => '2013',
    'data' => $data_array
);
```